# Where is Python's sys.path initialized from?

Tags: python, path, sys

Where is Python's sys.path initialized from?

**UPD**: Python is adding some paths before refering to PYTHONPATH:

```
    >>> import sys
    >>> from pprint import pprint as p
    >>> p(sys.path)
    ['',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\orbited-0.7.8-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\morbid-0.8.6.1-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\demjson-1.4-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\stomper-0.2.2-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\uuid-1.30-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\stompservice-0.1.0-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\cherrypy-3.0.1-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\pyorbited-0.2.2-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\flup-1.0.1-py2.5.egg',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\wsgilog-0.1-py2.5.egg',
     'c:\\testdir',
     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python25.zip',
     'C:\\Python25\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python25',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
     'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

My PYTHONPATH is:

```
    PYTHONPATH=c:\testdir
```

I wonder where those paths before PYTHONPATH's ones come from?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

"Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH, plus an installation-dependent default"

-- http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: I guess they come from the site module:

http://docs.python.org/library/site.html

Comment: The site module loads and parses the contents of any .pth files in your site-packages directory. These .pth files contain additions to your PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 129):

EDIT

When I wrote this back in 2015, there was no documentation on the subject. [There is now](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#the-initialization-of-the-sys-path-module-search-path) per the comments, if you wanted to also check that out. There is also a [prose explanation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/getpath.py#L72) of the algorithm in the comments of `getpath.py` in the code base. I still believe my answer to be relevant and relatively current.

ORIGINAL TEXT FOLLOWS

Python really tries hard to intelligently set [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path). How it is
set can get [really](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/getpath.c) [complicated](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/getpath.py). The following guide is a watered-down,
somewhat-incomplete, somewhat-wrong, but hopefully-useful guide
for the rank-and-file python programmer of what happens when python
figures out what to use as the *initial values* of `sys.path`,
`sys.executable`, `sys.exec_prefix`, and `sys.prefix` on a *normal*
python installation.

First, python does its level best to figure out its actual physical
location on the filesystem based on what the operating system tells
it. If the OS just says "python" is running, it finds itself in $PATH.
It resolves any symbolic links. Once it has done this, the path of
the executable that it finds is used as the value for `sys.executable`, no ifs,
ands, or buts.

Next, it determines the initial values for `sys.exec_prefix` and
`sys.prefix`.

If there is a file called `pyvenv.cfg` in the same directory as
`sys.executable` or one directory up, python looks at it. Different
OSes do different things with this file.

One of the values in this config file that python looks for is
the configuration option `home = <DIRECTORY>`. Python will use this directory instead of the directory containing `sys.executable`
when it dynamically sets the initial value of `sys.prefix` later. If the `applocal = true` setting appears in the
`pyvenv.cfg` file on Windows, but not the `home = <DIRECTORY>` setting,
then `sys.prefix` will be set to the directory containing `sys.executable`.

Next, the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable is examined. On Linux and Mac,
`sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` are set to the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable, if
it exists, *superseding* any `home = <DIRECTORY>` setting in `pyvenv.cfg`. On Windows,
`sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` is set to the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable,
if it exists, *unless* a `home = <DIRECTORY>` setting is present in `pyvenv.cfg`,
which is used instead.

Otherwise, these `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix` are found by walking backwards
from the location of `sys.executable`, or the `home` directory given by `pyvenv.cfg` if any.

If the file `lib/python<version>/dyn-load` is found in that directory
or any of its parent directories, that directory is set to be to be
`sys.exec_prefix` on Linux or Mac. If the file
`lib/python<version>/os.py` is is found in the directory or any of its
subdirectories, that directory is set to be `sys.prefix` on Linux,
Mac, and Windows, with `sys.exec_prefix` set to the same value as
`sys.prefix` on Windows. This entire step is skipped on Windows if
`applocal = true` is set. Either the directory of `sys.executable` is
used or, if `home` is set in `pyvenv.cfg`, that is used instead for
the initial value of `sys.prefix`.

If it can't find these "landmark" files or `sys.prefix` hasn't been
found yet, then python sets `sys.prefix` to a "fallback"
value. Linux and Mac, for example, use pre-compiled defaults as the
values of `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`.  Windows waits
until `sys.path` is fully figured out to set a fallback value for
`sys.prefix`.

Then, (what you've all been waiting for,) python determines the initial values
that are to be contained in `sys.path`.

1. The directory of the script which python is executing is added to `sys.path`.
   On Windows, this is always the empty string, which tells python to
   use the full path where the script is located instead.
2. The contents of PYTHONPATH environment variable, if set, is added to `sys.path`, *unless* you're
   on Windows and `applocal` is set to true in `pyvenv.cfg`.
3. The zip file path, which is `<prefix>/lib/python35.zip` on Linux/Mac and
   `os.path.join(os.dirname(sys.executable), "python.zip")` on Windows, is added to `sys.path`.
4. If on Windows and no `applocal = true` was set in `pyvenv.cfg`, then the contents of the subkeys of the registry key
   `HK_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\<DLLVersion>\PythonPath\` are added, if any.
5. If on Windows and no `applocal = true` was set in `pyvenv.cfg`, and `sys.prefix` could not be found,
   then the *core contents* of the of the registry key `HK_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\<DLLVersion>\PythonPath\` is added, if it exists;
6. If on Windows and no `applocal = true` was set in `pyvenv.cfg`, then the contents of the subkeys of the registry key
   `HK_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python\PythonCore\<DLLVersion>\PythonPath\` are added, if any.
7. If on Windows and no `applocal = true` was set in `pyvenv.cfg`, and `sys.prefix` could not be found,
   then the *core contents* of the of the registry key `HK_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\PythonCore\<DLLVersion>\PythonPath\` is added, if it exists;
8. If on Windows, and PYTHONPATH was not set, the prefix was not found, and no registry keys were present, then the
   relative compile-time value of PYTHONPATH is added; otherwise, this step is ignored.
9. Paths in the compile-time macro PYTHONPATH are added relative to the dynamically-found `sys.prefix`.
10. On Mac and Linux, the value of `sys.exec_prefix` is added. On Windows, the directory
    which was used (or would have been used) to search dynamically for `sys.prefix` is
    added.

At this stage on Windows, if no prefix was found, then python will try to
determine it by searching *all* the directories in `sys.path` for the landmark files,
as it tried to do with the directory of `sys.executable` previously, until it finds something.
If it doesn't, `sys.prefix` is left blank.

Finally, after all this, Python loads the `site` module, which adds stuff yet further to `sys.path`:

> It starts by constructing up to four directories from a head and a
> tail part. For the head part, it uses `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`;
> empty heads are skipped. For the tail part, it uses the empty string
> and then `lib/site-packages` (on Windows) or `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`
> and then `lib/site-python` (on Unix and Macintosh). For each of the
> distinct head-tail combinations, it sees if it refers to an existing
> directory, and if so, adds it to sys.path and also inspects the newly
> added path for configuration files.

---

EDIT: There is no more [`getpathp.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a4774f42e35861c4bb16928cffb011c2d8a285ac/PC/getpathp.c) (link at the beginning on **complicated** word) since [Dec 2021](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/29041/files#diff-e1cdb17c354ff4dd236c080589691ab82f18cd5a76ac34968b596512ceea9c6b) because implementation was ported to Python: [`getpath.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/getpath.py)

Comment: Despite what its docs say, `sys.executable` can be a symlink or actually it can be anything if `argv[0]` contains slashes. The actual *path* to the executable (from `execv(path, argv)` call) is not used.

Comment: Concerning your first point for `sys.path` on windows 10: I always get the full path of my script dir as sys.path[0] (not cwd ''). You should be able to execute something like `python some\other\path\than\cwd\main.py`

Comment: I agree with @ford04. Point 1 is incorrect: On Windows the script's directory is added to sys.path, not a blank path, nor cwd. This is in various Python 3.x installs.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! I saw about 10 other questions and answers before stumbling upon this, the "truth", even though you're humbling admitting you don't quite have it all.

Comment: I would add that relevant files in `site-packages` have `.pth` and `.egg-link` suffixes.

Comment: is there a way to initiate this flow when loading the Python engine from C? When I start the Python interpreter from the shell, `sys.path` contains many items, while when I start it from C (by calling `Py_Initialize()`), it only contains the interpreter's `Lib` directory (this is on Windows...)

Comment: @SomethingSomething if you follow the links in "really" and "complicated" above it will take you to the actual C functions that area responsible for building the `sys.path`, perhaps you can call those functions directly.

Comment: Python certainly has its warts. Initialization is definitely one of them. Packaging is another. The warty parts being lack of documentation, unclear legacy/future usage, and  leaky abstraction of the runtime environment.

Comment: Changed in version 3.6: Adds ._pth file support and removes applocal option from pyvenv.cfg.

Comment: A great answer, but by ignoring `sys.base_prefix` and most of PEP405 it's somehow misleading if one is trying to understand how virtual envs work. In the presence of a `home = DIR` in  `pyvenv.cfg`, all the above algorithm applies to `sys.base_prefix` instead, while `sys.prefix` is set to the virtual env. The [official PEP405 specification](https://peps.python.org/pep-0405/#specification) offers a detailed and friendly explanation.

Comment: @MestreLion, I read the C code in order to write this answer. I didn't actually know about PEP 405 when I wrote it. I didn't ignore the PEP, I just read the code :shrug:

Comment: There is also a section in official docs : [The initialization of the `sys.path` module search path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys_path_init.html#the-initialization-of-the-sys-path-module-search-path)

Comment: In short, sys.path doesn't inherit values from system PATH env variable.