# Can you import a Python module from a Windows symbolic link?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, python-import, symlink

I'm contributing to a Python 3 project from a Windows 7 computer.

In order to minimise clutter while making and testing changes, I'm placing a few test files inside a folder called `ignore` within the project, and excluding it from the version control system (Git).

There is no `__init__.py` file in the root of the project, so I thought I'd create a symbolic link from the module I want to test into the `ignore` folder, to enable me to import it.

```
mklink ignore\example.py example.py
```

When I try to import the module from a script in `ignore` I get an `ImportError` saying the `example` module doesn't exist.

Is it possible to import modules via symbolic links in this way? I understand that this is [*supposed* to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749108/python-import-symbolic-link-of-a-folder), but I can't find a reference saying that it works on Windows.

Comment: The target should be relative to the link, e.g. `mklink ignore\example.py ..\example.py`.

Comment: Huh, well there you go. I always assumed that `mklink` took paths relative to the current directory. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

I have just spent +2 hours trying to resolve this issue and 
it turned out that creating a Windows Directory Junction worked for me.

You don't need to use a relative one, it worked with both.

So first create an empty file `__init__.py` in your igonore-folder
then in the elevated mode (As Administrator) create a link:

> mklink /J ignore path-to-your-ignore-module

Then in your Python code you would be able to execute:
`from ignore.something import some-other-thing`