# Git Hooks not running on Windows

Tags: python, git

I have a repository which contains versioned git hooks. I have symbolic links (that are relative) inside the `.git/hooks` folder that point to my versioned git hooks. The git hooks are implemented in python and contain the `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line (which should be working https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#shebang-lines).

As part of my versioned git hooks - I have a pre-commit file and a `utils.py` file on the same level which is imported in the pre-commit script.

When I commit on my Mac the pre-commit successfully runs. However, when I commit on a Windows machine, my pre-commit script blows up on the line where `utils.py` is being imported and I have no idea why. What is going wrong, what have I missed?

EDIT: This is how I am generating my symbolic links. Note that I have used this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28382515/2155605 to make `os.symlink` work on unix and windows. Also note that when this script runs I am in the `.git/hooks` directory.

```
for hook in hooks_to_enable:
    os.chmod("../../git-hooks/" + hook, os.stat("../../git-hooks/" + hook).st_mode | 0o111)
    os.symlink(os.path.join("..", "..", "git-hooks", hook), hook)
```

EDIT: I may have narrowed down the problem. When I print my module search path (`sys.path`) in my versioned hook, it shows the search path from the `.hooks` directory so all the modules that are in the versioned hooks directory cannot be imported because they are not on the path. If I manually add them it works. However, when I do this same thing on Unix, the search path contains the directory of the versioned hook - not the `.git/hooks` directory - which is why it's working on Unix.

Comment: So the hook is running, but isn't running successfully to completion?  Could you share the error you're seeing, as well as the code around the line it fails on?

Comment: It fails on the first line `from utils import get_validation_error`. It can't find  my `utils.py` module.

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749214/6309 help?

Comment: @VonC They are relevant but it doesn't explain why my symlinks are specifically not working on windows.

Comment: @VonC Please see my edit on how I am generating the symlinks. I saw this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922742/can-you-import-a-python-module-from-a-windows-symbolic-link?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment69059582_40922742 Do you think this might be my problem?

Comment: What a `dir`done in a CMD return when done in the folder where your symlink has been created? Is it a folder junction? Or an actual folder link? (the latter would require administrative privilege to be correctly created)

Comment: @VonC It is an actual folder link - with windows I am running command prompt as an administrator when I run my script to create the links.

Comment: Please see my edit I may have narrowed down the problem