# Import Error: No module named django

Tags: python, django, centos, pythonpath

I am using centos linux.

I had python 2.6 with django and now i upgraded to python 2.7.
Python 2.6 is located in  /usr/lib/python2.6.
Python 2.7 is located in /usr/local/lib/python2.7.
They both have site-packages directory and they both contain django 1.2.

If i run python i get the 2.7 version.
My problem is that if try to import django i get

> ImportError: No module named django

I am not sure where is my PYTHONPATH defined and if this is what i need to change.
anyone ?

i ended up making a symbolic link to the 2.6 site-packages directory.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To check your path, you can use the following code:

```
import sys     
print(sys.path)
```

If you already know where django is installed, it should be easy to test if the desired directory is in your path with `directory in sys.path`.

Regarding where your `PYTHONPATH` is defined, note that it's an environment variable, so you can check its value (if defined) with: `echo $PYTHONPATH`

Comment: the direcroty is not in the path but the parent direcotory - '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' is in the path, how do i add a directory to that path ?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not defined, so where are all the directories that are in the sys.path are defined ?

Comment: In that case, python should be able to find django. Did you install it maybe as an egg?

Comment: Aside from `PYTHONPATH`, the contents of `sys.path` is populated using a value that depends on the installation. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/897792/183066).

Answer (score 56):

I had the same error, and this fix my issue

`python -m pip install django`

:) Done!

Comment: This worked for me - care to elaborate the difference on running this, as opposed to `pip install django`?

Comment: This is the correct answer, you helped me. Thank you.

Comment: I did this, and it says **Requirement already satisfied**. I got ***ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'address'*** after I changed the location of my django folder.

Answer (score 16):

Under linux, you can set the PYTHONPATH environment variable in your .profile or .bashrc.  You can either edit it directly from the terminal by changing to your home directory (cd ~), and then edit the file (nano .bashrc), or by opening the file with gtkedit or vim or whatever, and add:

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/another/path/etc
```

If you want to test this before editing your profile, you can export this from the terminal as:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I'm assuming you're running this straight from the command line.  If you're running it as a wsgi module in apache, you can add this to your syspath from your wsgi file as:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

Comment: I think the separator should be a ":" instead of a ";"

Comment: @YannSagon Thanks - fixed above.  Semi-colon would be for windows, but this was for centos, which would use a colon.

Answer (score 13):

try

```
pip freeze
```

this command show which packages are installed in your system
then run with root privilege

```
pip install django
```

then create a new project with command

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

then start your project

```
cd path/to/mysite
./manage.py runserver
```

in file wsgi.py add this lines

```
import os
import sys
DJANGO_PATH =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')
sys.path.append(DJANGO_PATH)
```

Answer (score 11):

Try printing `sys.path` to see what's in your path. Django need to be in one of the dirs listed. Example on Windows:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for p in sys.path: print p

C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\Python27\DLLs
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
>>>
```

Comment: how do i add a directory to this list ? if i use .append it does not presist

Answer (score 3):

django went missing with an upgrade to python 3.7

```
pip3 install django
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a environment use:

```bash
$ <environment_location>/<environment_name>/bin/python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 1):

`python3 -m django --version1`

for me it was that^

Answer (score 0):

I also had same error but easily solved it .those who are using version 4 and above of Django and python 3.0 can do the following(for windows)

**pip install virtualenv**   #installs virtual environment in pc

**py -m venv myvenv**        #creates virtual environment named myvenv inside folder

**myvenv/Scripts/activate**  # activates the virtual environment

You are now ready to go.

**pip install django**       # pip install django

**python -m django --version**  # checks the version of installed django