# ImportError for Gnuplot in python terminal

Tags: python, import, centos, gnuplot, importerror

I have **Gnuplot 4.2 patchlevel 6** installed on my Centos 6 system. However, whenever I try importing Gnuplot in the python terminal, I get an error message which says that there is no module named Gnuplot:

```
'>>> import Gnuplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Gnuplot`
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Python version is 2.6.6

Comment: what do you get by checking the paths? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462280/2375207

Comment: ['', '/usr/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/webkit-1.0']

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: Try installing  this python-gnuplot

Comment: and then, check if gnuplot is in any of your paths, in bash something like 

    for p in '/usr/lib/python26.zip', ...; do echo $p ; grep -r Gnuplot $p; done

Comment: nicolallias, i could not follow what you're asking me to do. could you please explain in detail?

Comment: I was suggesting to look for gnuplot in these folders using a shell command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
pip install gnuplot-py
```

If it does not work, try downloading the package from http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/ and install it.

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install gnuplot-py
```

didnot worked for me

```
Collecting gnuplot-py
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gnuplot-py (from versions: )
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external gnuplot-py to allow).
No matching distribution found for gnuplot-py
```

**but following did the job:**

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot-py/Gnuplot-py/1.8/gnuplot-py-1.8.tar.gz
tar xzf gnuplot-py-1.8.tar.gz
cd gnuplot-py-1.8/
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to

1. Clone:

   git clone https://github.com/jrk/gnuplot-py into the site-packages
2. Go to the installed directory use:

   python setup.py install