# ImportError: No module named django: Python 2.7.5

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a problem with the project which shows the following errors. This was the project which used to run a year ago but when i tried to run now in the same python version(2.7.5) but shows error. Can anyone help me to solve this error.

C:\Users\ss\Desktop\project_ss\src>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 119, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
ImportError: No module named django

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Error: No module named django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462212/import-error-no-module-named-django)

Comment: @TariiqHenryBbosa So do you mean having the same topic would solve all the problems?

Comment: But that is the same problem its about correcting the home path

Comment: From your Error i have learnt thats you could have installed Django but not in the right home path

Comment: ok, "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django-1.8.4-py2.7.egg" this is the path where django has been installed. Is it not the right place, because i didn't get the exact solution from the link you have pasted above.

Comment: Your PYTHONPATH environment variable is apparently not set to the right directories. Either set it to, or include, C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages .