# no module name 'django'

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I'm fairly new to Python and I am trying to create a website using Python 3.5. When I run the code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.text
```

I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "models.py"/ line 1, in (module)
  from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I tried installing django in the virtual environment again and got the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Django in c:\users\owner\documents\learning_log\11_env\lib\site-packages
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you activate the `virtualenv` before running the code?

Comment: Might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9462280/5110035

Comment: Did you run `django-admin startproject someProjectName` to create the necessary directories and files?

Comment: I have tried all of these things.

Comment: Try to run _python_ command on the terminal and _import django_. If the ImportError persists, you dont have the django package installed on this python path(env).

Comment: what environment are you trying to run this in?  A Django development server? WSGI? mod_python?  It's clearly a configuration problem somewhere but without knowing how you're running it, there's no good way to suggest where to start looking.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething If I'm not mistaken, It is a Django server.