# ImportError initialization error: ImportError: No module named session_csrf

Tags: python, installation, mozilla

I try to install pontoon.
I use the doc [here](https://mozilla-pontoon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/install.html) but when I make:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I have this error:

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
ImportError: No module named session_csrf
```

I have no idea. Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462212/import-error-no-module-named-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session_csrf is a module from the Django framework (see : [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-age)), it seems then Pontoon are using Django.
Your manage.py file can't found the module session_csrf.
try to install it with :

```
pip install django-session-csrf
```