# Deploying to Heroku: ImportError:Couldn't import Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, webdeploy

When I want to deploy my code to Heroku using
`git push heroku master`
I have `ImportError:Couldn't import Django`.
So I try `python manage.py runserver` to see what is going on and it shows this in the terminal.
[Full description of ImportError:Couldn't import Django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhiIC.png).
Before I tab all the process for deploying my code to Heroku,`python manage.py runserver` works well (the system gives me a link to open my Web page).

Here is my requirements.txt
[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDxkA.png)

Comment: Make sure that your Python Path is set correctly. It seems Heroku deployment causes a lot of errors these days with the Django projects. There are a bunch of threads around. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462212/import-error-no-module-named-django

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you deploy a python app to Heroku, you must have a requirements.txt file. I had this same error and when I added all of my dependencies to a requirements.txt file, it all worked. Best way to do this is if you are running on a virtual environment is

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have requirements.txt and Procfile in my folder.

Comment: @Jessica, please edit your question and show us your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Done! Do you know what I should do at any chance?

Comment: having the same issue. do you know how I can fix this?