# New python dot version not detecting installed modules?

Tags: python, pip

Using the /usr/local/bin install for Python 2.6.7 to keep it separate from Python 2.6.1 (see [Upgrade Python to 2.6 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541776/upgrade-python-to-2-6-on-mac)), my new 2.6.7 binary isn't finding my 2.6 modules when I try to run code.  As far as I understood, 2.6.1 and 2.6.7 should share modules because both are 2.6 modules.

```
ImportError: No module named unicodecsv
```

If I want to use my new `/usr/local/bin/python` (2.6.7) to run my program with modules I pip installed while using 2.6.1, what crucial step am I missing?  A path issue?  Using `/usr/bin/python` still imports the module without an issue.

I've confirmed that `/usr/local/bin/pip install unicodecsv` (and `pip-2.6 install`)
just tells me I already have what I need:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: unicodecsv in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

Comment: What does running both of the Python's show, when run using eg: `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`

Comment: Oh yes, that's definitely where I've failed.  The 2.6.7 path is missing `/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages` among other things.  Forgive my ignorance, I'm still a raging Python newbie ... is `sys.path` the same as `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697517/sys-path-and-pythonpath-issues

Comment: Modules playing nice now that I have PYTHONPATH set up properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` on the well-behaved binary that knows where the modules are to get correct paths.  (thank you, [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements).)

Create or update the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to capture these paths so that your new binary is searching the right places.

In bash, for example, just add it to `.bash_profile`:
`EXPORT PYTHONPATH=path:from:above:sys_path:inquiry`

And then re-execute to activate: `. ~/.bash_profile`