# Python sys.path internal?

Tags: python, path, sys

Recently, I copied a python project from different place and got below issue:

I installed python on `D:\python27`

then I checked sys.path using below code:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

I got below ouput:

```
...
'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 
'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
```

I have no idea where python append the old trash python install path into sys.path. Share any idea will be appreciated. Thanks!

PS: I also checked the PYTHONPATH variable in registry table:

```
D:\Python27\Lib;D:\Python27\DLLs;D:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check a few things:

- Verify that you do not have an older version of Python installed at c:\Python.
- Make sure to test the value of sys.path *before* importing or running anything else.
- If you still have the problem, try running Python directly from its installed path on your D: drive.

Good luck.

Comment: I had ever installed the older version in C:\python, but now it is not existing. Do you have any idea about how the python to build sys.path?

Comment: It looks to me that your older Python was not properly uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The registry is consulted when setting up `sys.path`. Unset the registry keys and your python `sys.path` should look cleaner. For more about how sys.path works, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/850326