# python sys.path implementation

Tags: python, windows, sys

today, I checked how sys.path got implemented by python. i found it points to sys.pi file(python 2.7.8 in windows). see code

```
argv = []
__stdout__ = file(__file__)
__name__ = 'sysoverride'
__stderr__ = file(__file__)
dllhandle = 0
exitfunc = None
stdin = file(__file__)
modules = {}
last_type = None
stderr = file(__file__)
path = []
last_value = None
hexversion = 17105408
```

my question is how python can print out a list of python paths with path=[] statement. it is really confused me.
Thanks

Comment: For more about how sys.path works, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/850326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc's](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

> **sys.path** is a list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. **Initialized from the environment variable PYTHONPATH**, plus an installation-dependent default.

In addition to that , there is a [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) module wich is **automatically imported during initialization** wich appends site-specific paths and builtins to the module search path .

Comment: "automatically imported during initialization" how does this work?