# Remove entry from sys.path

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

After installing some Python Modules via homebrew, homebrew told me to run the following code.
I don't need those modules anymore and want to cleanup everything. Can i remove (should i?) remove this entry? And how i remove it?

> Python modules have been installed and Homebrew's site-packages is not
>   in your Python sys.path, so you will not be able to import the modules
>   this formula installed. If you plan to develop with these modules,
>   please run:

```
mkdir -p /Users/rain/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/USERNAME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Mac OsX 10.10.2

Comment: pth files are read when the `site` module is loaded on python init, and so the above script would cause that directory to be put into your local homebrew python. You can remove it, since you're removing the python. For more about how sys.path works, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38403654/850326

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely delete `/Users/USERNAME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth` if you aren't using any Homebrew-installed python modules.

.pth files are a way of adding paths to `sys.path`. Lines in a .pth file which are paths are added to `sys.path`; lines in a .pth file starting with `import` are executed.

The line starting with `import` in the `homebrew.pth` file makes the site-packages directory under the Homebrew prefix a special site-packages directory, which both adds it to sys.path and ensures that any .pth files that it contains are read and processed.