# OpenCV not found in Jupyter Notebook, but found in Terminal

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I installed openCV in my environment using '''conda-forge'''.

It works in my terminal

```
❯ python
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 26 2020, 10:43:30) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
```

### But it doesn't work on my Jupyter Notebook

```
import cv2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I am using Python 3.8.2. It shows on my conda list and the environment package list of anaconda. Please help.

[image: The images show both environments having the openCV package]

Comment: I would guess you didn't install it in the environment used by jupyter. In Jupyter you can select different kernels. Check which kernel you're using on the kernel tab in notebook or the  button in the upper right in Lab.

Comment: It only has a Python 3 Kernel. I get the same error even when i run jupyter notebook from my environment with opencv installed in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cv2 import error on Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109270/cv2-import-error-on-jupyter-notebook) & [Import OpenCV on jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52832991/import-opencv-on-jupyter-notebook) & [Unable to import opencv in Jupyter notebook but able to import in command line on Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248940/unable-to-import-opencv-in-jupyter-notebook-but-able-to-import-in-command-line-o)

Comment: Thank you @Trenton. 

source activate Vision
python -m ipykernel install --user --name Vision --display-name "Python (Vision)"

Then selecting the Python (vision) from Jupyter Notebook solved this!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Trenton.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name Vision --display-name "Python (Vision)"
```

Then selecting the Python (vision) from Jupyter Notebook solved this!