# raspberrypi ImportError: No module named servicebus

Tags: python, linux, azure, raspberry-pi2

I am getting this error when running python script for Azure ServiceBus.

Is the file in the wrong location, or am I importing it incorrectly?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/letsroll $ python mrrobot.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mrrobot.py", line 6, in <module>
    from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
ImportError: No module named servicebus
```

**Azure SDK path:** `pi@raspberrypi:~/azure-sdk-for-python $`

**Python script path:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/letsroll $ ls

mrrobot.py
```

**mrrobot.py**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #For Controlling the Pins
import threading #To Run On Thread
import sys
import select
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusService
import os

# Make sure you set the following:
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_NAMESPACE='mrrobot' #Your NameSpace Should Go Here
# Note: this user should have manage rights
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_SHARED_KEY_NAME='RootManageSharedAccessKey'
AZURE_SERVICEBUS_ACCESS_KEY_VALUE='MpcCdemokey'
GPIO_BCM_PIN = 17 #Pin your LED is connected to
```

Comment: why it had been down voted

Comment: Well, your question was formatted very badly to start with, and hard to understand. I've improved it the best I can.

Comment: @SiHa That's not a valid reason to downvote...You should know when to downvote.

Comment: I didn't down-vote. I had a stab at improving it so that hopefully nobody else would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python interpreter does not found the packages. It can be for several reasons:

- You didn't install correctly the SDK (files are missing). You can use pip, "git clone" from the repo directly, or copy/pasting the "azure-servicebus" zip from PyPI and unzip it. Since you didn't share the content of your `pi@raspberrypi:~/azure-sdk-for-python` folder, I can't tell. Don't forget the dependencies if you manually install the code.
- Your path to packages is not well defined. Again, can be fixed several ways, by defining a [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) or changing your [sys.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/where-is-pythons-sys-path-initialized-from)