# Jupyter Notebook has wrong sys.path, cannot load packages from anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

EDIT: I have now fixed this problem by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46641050/9454052)

I am trying to use Jupyter Notebook with anaconda. I have installed anaconda and when I run python in the shell it has the correct anadonda sys.path:

```
python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

However, when I do the same within Jupyter notebook, the `sys.path` has not been updated from when I installed anaconda:

```
import sys
print ('\n'.join(sys.path))

/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload

/home/morgan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/morgan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/home/morgan/.ipython
```

This has been a problem as I could not load packages installed using conda into Jupyter Notebook. I tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50305652/9454052), in which the `ipython_config` file is edited to add additional entries to the `sys.path`, so now when I print `sys.path` in Jupyter Notebook it gives me this:

```
/usr/lib/python36.zip
/usr/lib/python3.6
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload

/home/morgan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/home/morgan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions
/home/morgan/.ipython
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages /home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7 
/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
```

I have found including only `/home/morgan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages` allows jupyter notebook to find packages installed using conda, but it causes matplotlib to break. Including all three additional addresses causes it to not be able to find the packages at all.

I would like to be able to edit the `sys.path` for Jupyter Notebook directly as using this solution I can only add lines, not delete the lines that are already there.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter Notebook.

I am running the `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` as a Linux subsystem within Windows 10 (I am running everything including Jupyter notebook through this). As you can see I have `python 3.7` installed from `anaconda` and `python 3.6` in `.local/lib`.

Comment: Are you running Jupyter notebook from within an activated conda environment?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when **Jupyter** Notebook gets opened from another python **environment**. In Linux, you can work with native environments

Create python3 environment

```
python3 -m venv myenv
```

Activate the environment

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

Install jupyter notebook inside the activated environment

```
pip install jupyter notebook
```

Then install your modules and open **Jupyter notebook** inside that environment via

`jupyter notebook` command