# Import module throwing error when used in main.py, but working outside project

Tags: python, import

I have the following project structure

```
project
├───common
│   ├───__init__.py
│   └───Logger.py
├───config
│   └───configurations.xml
├───main.py
├───tests
│   └───input_file.xml
└───tools
    ├───RWOReaderDataSeries
    │   └───...
    ├───RWOReaderMap
    │   └───...
    ├───SimulatorRunner
        ├───__init__.py
        ├───main.py
        ├───Runner.py
        └───ConfigurationFile.py
```

I'm trying to use Runner.py in project\main.py, but I always go an error message.

project\SimulatorRunner\Runner.py imports:

```
import os
from ConfigurationFile import ConfigurationFile
```

And project\main.py imports:

```
import logging
import datetime
import tools.RWDWriterDataSeries.InputData as RWDWDSID
import tools.RWDWriterDataSeries.RWDWriter as RWDWDSW
import tools.SimulatorRunner.Runner as SimRunner
```

When I execute "project\SimulatorRunner\main.py" it works.

But when I execute "project\main.py", i got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Documents\Solpe\Shift\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tools.SimulatorRunner.Runner as SimRunner
  File "C:\Users\Fernanda\Documents\Solpe\Shift\tools\SimulatorRunner\Runner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ConfigurationFile import ConfigurationFile
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigurationFile'
```

This is the only import that is not working.

Comment: What is your `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work from `~/project/main.py` because there is no `~/project/ConfigurationFile` module. It does work from `~/project/tools/SimulatorRunner/main.py` because there *is* a `~/project/tools/SimulatorRunner/ConfigurationFile` module.

This is because Python uses a really complicated system to infer where modules should be loaded from in relation to the executing script (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/where-is-pythons-sys-path-initialized-from) for more details).

To view `sys.path`, at the start of your script, you can use:

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint as p
p(sys.path)
```

I would suspect different results from `project/main.py` compared to `project/tools/SimulationRunner/main.py`.

One way to solve this would be to add `~/project` to your PYTHONPATH (so Python stops guessing) and reference `ConfigurationFile` like this: `from tools.SimulationRunner.ConfigurationFile import ConfigurationFile`.