# What is the idea behind "the installation-dependent default" directory layout?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-import

Python's docs state that `sys.path` is initialized from the following locations:

1. the directory containing the input script,
2. `PYTHONPATH`, and
3. "the installation-dependent default".

`print(',\n'.join(sys.path))` produces the following output on my system (no script given, no `PYTHONPATH` set, Ubuntu):

```
,
/usr/lib/python36.zip,
/usr/lib/python3.6,
/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload,
/home/owl/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages,
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages,
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

So, except `''` apparently all the directories belong to "the installation-dependent default".

**What is the idea behind this directory layout?**

Why five different directories? Which modules go where?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/where-is-pythons-sys-path-initialized-from